# React router best practices for nested navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a React application, and using React Router for managing routing. The information architecture of the application can be represented as follows:

```
 - App
     - Projects
         - Project 1
             - Objects
               - Object 1
               - Object 2
               - etc...
             - Collaborators
         - ...
     - Services
     - Users
```

The UI of the application would look something like this, when looking at a route such as `/#/projects/1/components/1`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|            | Home > Projects > 0 > Object > 1           |
|  Home      |--------------------------------------------|
|            |                                            |
|  Projects  |   Object 1                                 |
|            |                                            |
|  Services  |   Blah blah blah                           |
|            |                                            |
|  Users     |                                            |
|            |                                            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that for any given route shown in the information architecture scheme above, the view should be rendered in the body section (where 'Component 1' is rendered in the diagram above).

Now I will describe how I have been wrongly implementing this in React using React Router:

I have been using PlainRoutes to define my routes. Here is a short example of how a route is defined:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: App,
        name: 'Home',
        childRoutes: [
          // /projects
          {
              path: 'projects',
              component: Projects,
              name: 'Projects'
          },
          {
              path: 'projects/:projectid',
              component: ProjectDetails,
              name: 'Project Details',
              childRoutes: [
                  {
                       path: 'objects',
                       component: Objects,
                       name: 'Objects'
                  },
                  {
                      path: 'objects/:objectid',
                      component: ObjectDetails,
                      name: 'Object Details'
                  },
                  {
                      path: 'collaborators',
                      component: Collaborators,
                      name: 'Collaborators'
                  }
              ]
          },
          // /services
          {
              path: 'services',
              component: Services,
              name: 'Services'
          },
          // /users
          {
              path: 'users',
              component: Users,
              name: 'Users'
          }
      ]
   }
];
```

which then get fed into the React Router component, like this: `<Router routes={routes}></Router>`

Doing this sort of worked. When I would attempt to navigate to:

`/#/projects`

I would see the Projects component rendered in the body of the app.

When I would attempt to navigate to:

`/#/projects/1`

I would see the ProjectDetail component rendered in the body of the app.

However, when I would attempt to navigate to:

`/#/projects/1/objects`

I would still see the ProjectDetail component rendered in the body of the app. I am not sure why the router would just stop when the `/projects/:projectid` parameter was resolved, and not continue to render components assigned to the `/projects/:projectid/objects` route.

I think that the problem was that I was using React Router in the wrong way. Child routes are supposed to be physically nested inside their parent components - not just logically nested. At least, I think that is the problem. Clearly, I am a bit confused as to how React Router is intended to be used - especially the concept of `childRoutes`.

The question then is - how to use React Router to give the application the hierarchical structure that I am seeking, as outlined above? I want the router to be aware of the deeply nested structure of the application (for things like breadcrumbs and navigation), but I don't want to physically nest the components inside one another. What are best practices here?

Comment: does `ProjectDetails` component use `this.props.children` ? If not, the `Objects` component will have no place to render. Do you want them both on the screen at the same time or just one or the other?

Comment: `ProjectDetails` does not use `this.props.children`. I want to render one or the other. So, it sounds like for each level of the hierarchy, I need to create an empty container, with an `indexRoute` to show if we are not showing a child. Would that be the correct way to go?

Comment: No just don't nest them. I added an answer, but wanted to ask you, for what reason were you nesting here? Just for sharing a piece of the string?

Comment: I want the router to keep track of the active routes, so I can know what routes are active, and where I am in the app. I want to know more than just the currently active route - I want to know the current path as well. I can derive this from the path of the current route by doing some string parsing, but I figured there might be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that you do not want to show both `ProjectDetails` and `Objects` at the path `/#/projects/1/objects`, then you do not want to nest these routes.

```
childRoutes: [
      // /projects
      {
          path: 'projects',
          component: Projects,
          name: 'Projects'
      },
      {
          path: 'projects/:projectid',
          component: ProjectDetails,
          name: 'Project Details',
      },
      {
          path: 'projects/:projectid/objects',
          component: Objects,
          name: 'Objects'
      },
      {
          path: 'projects/:projectid/objects/:objectid',
          component: ObjectDetails,
          name: 'Object Details'
      },
```

You would nest routes only if you were intending `Objects` to be populated inside `this.props.children` of `ProjectDetails`.

Comment: Right - that seems like another way that would work. The only problem with that method is Router doesn't seem to understand the information hierarchy. For example, if I want to build a breadcrumb trail, I would think that I would want to get that information from the `routes` prop (passed down from the `App` component, which is using `withRouter`. When I navigate to `/#/projects/1/objects/1`, the `routes` array contains just two routes: `['Home','Object 1']`. I would want it to be `['Home','Projects','Project 1','Objects','Object 1']`

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't get back to you about this. There's probably a clever solution for the breadcrumbs / active route that's not obvious to me without being hacky (checking location). Maybe using nested routes with plural named components instead of `children`

Comment: No worries - I figured out a solution using something similar to what you suggested - though I had to resort to parsing the current route's full path to build the breadcrumbs and appropriate navigation elements. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you can check this.props.children in Project Details Components. And you can write a render method of Project Details as below

```
render(){
   this.props.children?this.props.children:<Project Details/>
}
```

This will check if children available, then it will render their children otherwise it will render Project Details.